# Undefined reference to _write, which is implemented in a library

Tags: c, gcc, arm

I'm getting undefined reference to _write, required by a printf statement, in my embedded project. Using arm-none-eabi-gcc 9.3.1.

uart.c implements _write, as shown below:

```
int _write(int file, char* ptr, int len) __atribute__ ((used));
int _write(int file, char* ptr, int len)
{
   ...
}
void foo()
{
   nop();
}
```

uart.c is compiled into a static library, which is linked while compiling the executable.

Here is main.c:

```
int main()
{
   //foo();
   printf("Hello world!");
}
```

With `foo();` commented out, I get `undefined reference to '_write'`. With `foo();` uncommented, the project builds as expected. How can I get it to build without including a dummy function?

Build steps:

```
arm-none-eabi-gcc -c uart.c
ar rvs uart.a uart.o
arm-none-eabi-gcc main.c uart.a
```

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Nope, not in this case. Objdump of the library grepping write returns:
`00000000 g     F .text._write 00000018 _write`

Comment: `uart.c is compiled into a static library, which is linked while compiling the executable.` Please show the compilation commands. What is the order of arguments?

Comment: @KamilCuk I updated the question with my build steps

Comment: Could you please also post verbatim all error messages you are getting? Don't you get `undefined reference to _lseek` `undefined reference to _exit` etc? Also `s/__atribute__/__attribute__`, please.

Comment: @KamilCuk The files I posted are just a simplification of my large cmake project. The only error I am getting in the cmake project is: `writer.c:(.text._write_r+0x10): undefined reference to '_write'`. Yes, I get undefined reference to those others as well, but in my cmake project I don't because they are defined in other files that are linked properly.

Comment: Please create a _full_ [MCVE] next time.

Comment: @ryan.walton.256 - welcome to StackOverflow!  Please, if someone answers your question in a way that solves your problem (as you wrote in a comment on the answer below), please mark the answer as 'accepted' by clicking the checkbox under the voting arrows/score

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the standard library is linked *after* your library:

```
arm-none-eabi-gcc -v main.c uart.a
...
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/11.1.0/collect2 ....
        uart.a
        --start-group -lgcc -lc --end-group
        /usr/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/11.1.0/crtend.o /usr/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/11.1.0/crtn.o
```

which makes sense, but then `-lc` can't find stuff from `uart.a`. You can:

1. include `-lc` yourself first before `uart.a`
2. or use `--whole-archive` and include `uart.a`.

Tested with:

```
// main.c
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    printf("Hello wolrd\n");
}

// uart.c
#define nop()  __asm__("nop")
void _exit(int a) { for(;;); }
int _sbrk() { return -1; }
int _close() { return -1; }
int _read() { return -1; }
int _fstat() { return -1; }
int _isatty() { return -1; }
int _lseek() { return -1; }

int _write(int file, char* ptr, int len)
{
   nop();
}
void foo()
{
   nop();
}

// Makefile
all:
    arm-none-eabi-gcc -c uart.c
    ar rvs uart.a uart.o
    arm-none-eabi-gcc main.c -lc uart.a
    arm-none-eabi-gcc main.c -Wl,--whole-archive uart.a -Wl,--no-whole-archive
```

Comment: Ah thanks so much this fixed it! Sorry about the non full minimal reproducible example, I wasn't really sure how the cmake build worked anyway.